# ¿Por que no se reconoce el comando pip si el modulo esta instalado en Python?

Tags: python

Acabo de instalar Python 3.6.4 en un servidor de pruebas en debian 8, **no posee accesso a internet**.

Utilice el siguiente comando

```
tar xvhf Python-3.6.4.gz
cd  Python-3.6.4
./configure 
make
su make altinstall
```

Una vez listo, trate de usar pip y no funciono, procedi a reinstalar usando este comando:

```
./configure --ensurepip=yes
```

Eso con el fin de instalar pip en el caso que no estuviera.

Regreso el siguiente resultado:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

Es decir, que esta instalado el pip, pero al tratar de usarlo me dice lo siguiente:

bash: pip: no se encontro la orden.

Por otro lado, ingrese al interprete y utilice los siguientes comandos:

```
help()
modules
```

Observe que no esta pip ni setuptools y en una instalacion que tengo si aparecen.

**¿De que manera puedo hacer que pip funcione para poder instalar modulos de manera offline?**

Utilice este comando tambien para generar la variable de entorno:

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages"
```

Comment: Puede que el directorio donde se encuentra el pip no este incluido en tu variable de entorno PATH

Comment: @Sacha actualice la pregunta. voy a buscar usar el PYTHONPATH

Comment: @Sacha, ya descubri porque no sirve, estaba usando python3 en la consola y me arrojaba la version 3.4.2 y resulta que yo instale fue la 3.6 ahora ya funciona

Comment: No hubiera sido más fácil hacer `sudo apt-get install -y python3-pip`?

Comment: @amenadiel el problema es que el servidor no posee internet, olvide colocar eso.

Comment: oops, eso cambia todo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ocurre que debian 8 ya trae una version por defecto de `Python2.7`

Esta no contenia el modulo `pip` ni tampoco `setuptools`.

A la hora de instalar `Python3.6` debía acceder a el usando `Python3.6` en el `cli`, para poder ejecutar los comandos con la instalación que poseía los anteriores módulos nombrados.

Una vez cambie el comando `python` por `python3.6` en el `cli`, funciono, dando advertencias de los certificados `SSL` (por la falta de conexion a internet) pero funcionando correctamente.